# Hybrid Software Development Methodology

Tags: scrum, software-development, extreme-programming

Hybrid, Scrum and XP an agile methodologies. My Question is what is the different between them and what is better or the greatest methodology?

Thanx ... :)

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. I'm afraid this appears to be a question that will elicit opinions rather than absolute answers: if there were to be one methodology that was "greater" than the others, there would be no need to ask the question as everyone would use the same one. Please try to rephrase the question, including an explanation of why you are asking this, and explaining what research you have already carried out. That way there is more chance that you will obtain a helpful answer.

Comment: Lain is right that the "better or the greatest" part of the question is very subjective. I don't see any reason not to answer the rest of it though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid I can't give a comprehensive answer to that question on a forum like this, but I'll try to give the general idea.

First, between Scrum and XP. Scrum provides a framework for projects with a focus primarily on team collaboration and delivery of value on an ongoing, incremental basis. It's pretty light-weight a provides a couple of roles and a set of events that should occur each "Sprint", it 2 - 4 week iteration. I don't want to go into too much more detail because you can read all about it in the official scrum guide here:

http://www.scrumguides.org/

Being a very light-weight framework, Scrum leaves a lot of the day-to-day details up to the team. XP, on the other hand, provides a set of best practices for the day-to-day including user stories for defining what work should be done in the backlog. It also delves into test-driven development, paired programming, and other development practices. Some of these have been all but officially adopted in scrum (I've never met a scrum team that didn't use user stories for example) while others are hit-or-miss (paired programming is far less common).

This link has a pretty good overview of XP practices: http://xprogramming.com/what-is-extreme-programming/

The phrase "hybrid" is a little confusing because it can mean many things. Scrum/XP or Scrum/Kanban can be hybrid, but people also use it to mix things like Kanban and Waterfall or other completely non-agile approaches. In agile approaches like Scrum, XP, and Kanban, hybrid approaches can work well, but you need to be careful that you don't end up mixing them in a way that causes more problems. The Agile/Waterfall hybrids are less successful for two reasons: first, many of the practices are directly opposed to each other, so finding complimentary aspects of the two can be difficult. Second, most waterfall/agile hybrids are done out of a fear of committing to Agile, leaving the team doing neither Agile or Waterfall well and causing more grief for themselves than if they just went with one of them.

Answer (score 1):

In many ways Scrum and XP are complementary. Scrum is focused on the project/product management side while XP has a lot of focus on the engineering practices (like test driven development, continuous integration, refactoring, pair programming etc.).

There is an argument that good engineering practices are necessary for the success of Scrum. This is particularly true when the team is releasing frequently. As XP offers a lot of useful engineering practices you can see how mixing the two frameworks can be an effective approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no process which is applicable to all different kind of projects. For example scrum will not work **support projects** where we support calls get logged every hour. This is because we cant establish a sprint goal for such a kind of project.
Also scrum may be applicable for projects which are involved in work related to innovation for the same reasons.